# Forces on a bob on a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

A bob of 15 kg is attached to a 4 m long string and is moved to an initial position where the wire is making an angle of 35° with respect to the vertical and is held stationary by one's hand.

I'm having trouble determining if I am correct about what forces are acting upon the bob, as well as finding the unknown values of both the applied force and tension acting upon it. So far, my free-body diagram looks like this:

[image]

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Edit: I wasn't really thinking. If I'm correct, tension should be mgcosϴ as well, right?

Comment: Homework-like and check-my-work like questions should ask about a specific physics concept and show some effort to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See [How do I ask homework questions?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [Are check-my-work questions on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagram is incorrect; you should not have the two horizontal forces in the diagram.

Let $t = 0$ be the time at which the hand releases the bob. At any time $t>0$, there are only 2 forces acting on the bob: the weight and the tension. The diagram at $t=0$  should look like this:

1) The string is at $35^\circ$ wrt the vertical.

2) The tension $\vec T$ is upwards along the string.

3) The weight $\vec W$ with magnitude $mg$ is vertically downwards.

Thus, at any time $t > 0$, the string makes an angle $\theta(t)$ wrt to the vertical, where $\theta(t=0) = 35^\circ$. The total force acting on the bob is $$\vec F(t) = \vec T(t) + \vec W. \quad(1)$$

Note that if you project this equation onto the axis parallel to the string, then the component of the total force along this axis is zero, giving you

$$ T = mg\cos\theta(t), \quad (2)$$

and the tangential component of the total force is 
$$F_t = mg\sin\theta(t). \quad(3) $$